# Customization of new account email template in woocoommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add header & footer image in New account mail template in woocoomerce. Default template of new account is as follow

[image]

I am trying to add header & footer in this template only.(image attached for better clarification)

[image]

**Issue -** Added Images are not showing in user's mail box.

**What i have tried -**

I copied the customer-new-account.php file to my child theme folder & added the image. But it does not showing the image in.
Path of file -

> my-child-theme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.

My custom code is -

```
 defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<img src= 'Path of header image'>


<?php /* translators: %s: Customer username */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $user_login ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %1$s: Site title, %2$s: Username, %3$s: My account link */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Thanks for creating an account on %1$s. Your username is %2$s. You can access your account area to view orders, change your password, and more at: %3$s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $blogname ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_login ) . '</strong>', make_clickable( esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ) ) ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></p>
<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) && $password_generated ) : ?>
    <?php /* translators: %s: Auto generated password */ ?>
    <p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Your password has been automatically generated: %s', 'woocommerce' ), '<strong>' . esc_html( $user_pass ) . '</strong>' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php
/**
 * Show user-defined additional content - this is set in each email's settings.
 */
if ( $additional_content ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( $additional_content ) ) );
}

<img src= 'Path of footer image'>

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Any Advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was issue with `https` and `http`. The SSL-certificate was expired for the domain I was working on.

Due to this image was not displaying in user's mailbox. After fixing the SSL issue everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a couple of things.

**My best guess**

Is that you didn't put the template in the right location. That's a classic. So if it was me, then I would first ensure that 'customer-new-account.php` is in the right place. Perhaps read more about it here [WooCommerce template structure](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

**Other comments**

- It could also be some caching. It seem to remember caching with those emails being troublesome.
- Have you tried simply setting a new header-image in the WooCommerce backend (WooCommerce >> Settings >> Email >> Header image)? There is a 'Footer text' in there as well.
- I usually go for using a plugin when modifying the mails a lot, since it's actually quite a bit of work (just so you're aware).

Comment: Thanks Zeth for reply. I placed the file in this location my-child-theme/woocommerce/emails/customer-new-account.php.& i also tried to change it via WooCommerce Settings → Emails, but it added the image in all the templates like order & refund etc. 
I want to change only new user account creation mail.

Comment: Do you see any of your changes in the email? Perhaps if you just try and make a simple change first and see if that 'goes through'? I usually use the 'Preview Email'-plugin, to quickly see that changes I make. https://da.wordpress.org/plugins/woo-preview-emails/ (no relation to it).

Comment: yes i checked. I added simple image tag after the woocommerce_email_header action but image is not showing.

Comment: I think this issue is related to HTTPS & Non-HTTPS because image is showing in preview but not showing in users mail box. I am consulting with hosting provider.will update here if i found some thing. Thanks Zeth

Comment: Hi Zeth. This was an issue related to HTTPS, which is now fixed.

Comment: @Siddharth - Awesome! Glad you fixed it. Remember to mark a solution, if there is one (or if you pointed you in the right direction). If no solutions was right, then you can submit an answer yourself, so others who find this in the future, can follow your path to the solution. :-)

Comment: Thanks @zeth. I added my solution.